# How to find files by typing a column property?

Tags: search, column

I'd like to know how to find documents inside all SharePoint libraries ("all folders") by typing a property name inside a custom column. Is it possible?

For example, I create I column called "project code" and every time someone saves a file he/she must to insert the code of the project that file belongs to.

Next, I'd like to go to a search box, type such code and find all files related to it.

Comment: Thanks, I've just find the answer:

https://support.office.com/en-za/article/Manage-the-search-schema-in-SharePoint-Online-d4fab46d-ba41-4c03-9d4c-32b5b33198b6#bkmkcreateamanagedproperty

We need to index the column to validate it in searches.

Comment: Follow up if you run into issues. My blog has all this info in detail.